# Как связать два списка?

Tags: java, list

Как связать два списка, чтобы если в этом основном списке удалить объект условный производитель товаров, то удалить все данные производителя из другого списка [[pr1, zzz, 25, 50, pr2, xxx, 26, 75, pr3 , cccc, 27, 100], [a1, tttt, a2, yyyyy, a3, uuuuu]] во втором списке есть производители, то есть а1, а2, а3 и город производства (буду делать по аналогии).А если удалить а3, например, то удалить пр3, cccc, 27, 100.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        static List<Object> listSouvenirs = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Object> listManufacturer = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); //
    
    
    
    
        public static void listAddSouvenirs(Souvenirs s){
            listSouvenirs.add(s.getName());
            listSouvenirs.add(s.getInfo());
            listSouvenirs.add(s.getDate());
            listSouvenirs.add(s.getPrice());
        }
    
        public static void listAddManufacturer(Manufacturer m) {
            listManufacturer.add(m.getName());
            listManufacturer.add(m.getCountry());
        }
    
        public int menu1() {
    
            boolean b;
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter product name, manufacturer information, date of manufacture and price");
                String prodStr1 = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] souvenirs = prodStr1.split("  ");
                Menu.listAddSouvenirs(new Souvenirs(souvenirs[0], souvenirs[1], souvenirs[2], souvenirs[3]));
                System.out.println("Enter manufacturer's name, manufacturer's city");
                String prodStr2 = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] manufacturer = prodStr2.split("  ");
                Menu.listAddManufacturer(new Manufacturer(manufacturer[0], manufacturer[1]));
                System.out.println("Enter Y or y to continue");
                String check = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                b = check.contains("y");
            } while (b);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Maybe something else to read, tell me in this direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, у вас маппинг идет по индексу, тогда решение в лоб будет удаление по индексам, высчитывая их из позиции для удаления.

```
int position = listManufacturer.indexOf("a3");
listManufacturer.remove(position + 1);
listManufacturer.remove(position);
int position2 = position / 2 * 4;
listSouvenirs.remove(position2 + 3);
listSouvenirs.remove(position2 + 2);
listSouvenirs.remove(position2 + 1);
listSouvenirs.remove(position2);
```

Но по хорошему в Java нужно работать с объектами и обертками над ними, которые будут делать всю работу за вас, а не линейно обрабатывать код на низком уровне. Чем сложнее управление, тем проще это будет делать через классы. Особенно когда у вас данные будут уже не 1 производитель к 1 сувениру как сейчас.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.*;

public class Menu {
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Souvenirs {
        String name;
        String info;
        String date;
        String price;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Manufacturer {
        String name;
        String country;
    }


    public class Helper {
        private List<Souvenirs> souvenirs = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Manufacturer> manufacturers = new ArrayList<>();

        public void deleteManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
            int index = manufacturers.indexOf(manufacturer);
            manufacturers.remove(index);
            souvenirs.remove(index);
        }
    }

    public List<Object> getSouvenirsFlatList(List<Souvenirs> souvenirs){
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(var souvenir : souvenirs) {
            result.add(souvenir.name);
            result.add(souvenir.info);
            result.add(souvenir.date);
            result.add(souvenir.price);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public List<Object> getManufaturersFlatList(List<Manufacturer> manufacturers){
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(var souvenir : manufacturers) {
            result.add(souvenir.name);
            result.add(souvenir.country);
        }
        return result;
    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static List<Object> listSouvenirs = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Object> listManufacturer = new ArrayList<>();

    public void menu1() {
        Helper helper = new Helper();

        boolean b;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter product name, manufacturer information, date of manufacture and price");
            String prodStr1 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] souvenirs = prodStr1.split("  ");
            helper.souvenirs.add(new Souvenirs(souvenirs[0], souvenirs[1], souvenirs[2], souvenirs[3]);
            System.out.println("Enter manufacturer's name, manufacturer's city");
            String prodStr2 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] manufacturer = prodStr2.split("  ");
            helper.manufacturers.add(new Manufacturer(manufacturer[0], manufacturer[1]));
            System.out.println("Enter Y or y to continue");
            String check = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            b = check.contains("y");
        } while (b);

        // Удаление
        Manufacturer manufacturer = helper.manufacturers.stream().filter(x -> x.name.equals("a3")).findFirst().get();
        helper.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer);
        
        // Заполнение свойств можно сделать когда угодно и обновить данные
        listSouvenirs = getSouvenirsFlatList(helper.souvenirs);
        listManufacturer = getManufaturersFlatList(helper.manufacturers);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Menu().menu1();
    }
}
```